# ASP.NET Hide/disable entire dropdown menu based on user role

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list in an ASP.NET webform application generated in the sitemaster menu using the follow ing code:

```
   <li class="dropdown" id="Admin" > <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Admin<span class="caret" ></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                                <li><a  runat="server" href="~/Admin/Members">Members Management</a></li>
                               <li ><a  runat="server" href="~/Admin/MembersRegistry">Members Registry</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                </li>
```

and the script to generate the drop down is

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
        //toggle the open class (on/off)
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
})
</script>
```

I want to be able to hide or show the entire dropdown menu based on user roles:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Admin.Visible = false;
       
        

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            
            
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>(); 
           
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            if (manager.IsInRole(user, "Admin"))
            {
                Admin.Visible = true;
              
            }

           
        }
    }
```

But this is not working and the Admin control is not accessible from the code behind, any thoughts or suggestions please?

Comment: in the page_load, the item is set to invisible first (but this is not working either): Admin.Visible = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a runat="server" tag to that, then your code behind should see/have use of that controls, and you code looks like it should work ok.

eg:

```
<li class="dropdown" id="Admin" runat="server">
  .etc. etc.

</li>
```

Comment: Your control needs the runat="server" tag. I will disagree though, that you should use the visible tag. I'm always a fan of hiding things with CSS `admin.style.add("display","none")` or setting them to disabled `admin.enabled = false` instead of invisible so that they can be better manipulated on the page with JavaScript later if needed.

Comment: I tend to agree, and if you use visiable=false, then that markup is not even generated/sent to the browser. However, since it is a menu, then it probably ok, and thus users with less rights can't hit f12 and "see" the URL's for say the admin person. I would assume that such pages are secured, but I am "ok" with in this case using visible=false, but often that is a "bad" habit, since client side js code will fail on getelement. (and worse, in the above posted code? - it looks like js code does try to select that element). (so, I have  up-voted your comment).